# Смена цвета item RecyclerView при нажатии

Tags: android, kotlin

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на itemView внутри RecyclerView выбранный itemView окрашивался в другой цвет.

Для этого я сделал отдельный параметр для бизнес - класса

```
isSelected
```

**Model**

```
data class RecordItem(
    val id: Int,
    val name : String,
    val filePath: String,
    val duration: Duration,
    val createdDateTime: DateTime,
    val isSelected : Boolean = false
){
    fun toEntity() : RecordEntity{
        return RecordEntity(id, name, filePath, duration, createdDateTime)
    }
}
```

Создал метод handleSelectedItem(), который буду передавать в adapter

```
class RecordListViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: RecordRepository): ViewModel() {
    private var records =  repository.getAllRecording()

    fun getAllRecords() = records

    fun handleSelectedItem(id : Int){

        records = Transformations.map(records){
            new -> new.map {
            if(it.id == id) it.copy(isSelected = true)
            else it.copy(isSelected = false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
private fun initViews(root : View){
        recordListAdapter = RecordListAdapter {viewModel.handleSelectedItem(it.id)}
        val divider = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)

        with(root.rv_record_list){
            adapter = recordListAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            addItemDecoration(divider)
        }
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
class RecordListAdapter (
    private val listener : (RecordItem) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordListAdapter.RecordListItemViewHolder>(){

    var items : List<RecordItem> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecordListItemViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_record_list, parent, false)
        return RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecordListItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position], listener)
    }

    fun updateData(data : List<RecordItem>){
        val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.Callback(){
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                items[oldItemPosition].id == data[newItemPosition].id


            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean =
                items[oldItemPosition].hashCode() == data[newItemPosition].hashCode()

            override fun getOldListSize(): Int = items.size

            override fun getNewListSize(): Int = data.size
        }

        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        items = data
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    inner class RecordListItemViewHolder(convertView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(convertView),
        LayoutContainer {
        override val containerView: View?
            get() = itemView

        fun bind(record : RecordItem, listener: (RecordItem) -> Unit){
            if(record.isSelected){
                ////попытка менять цвет
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
                itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
            }
            itemView.tv_name.text = record.name
            itemView.tv_duration.text = record.duration.millis.toStringTime()
            itemView.tv_date_created.text = record.createdDateTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener.invoke(record)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Элемент к сожалению не меняется.

Что я делаю не правильно?
Подозреваю, что handleSelectedItem не правильно работает, но не пойму в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

Вы как-то очень всё замудрили, если вы состояние элемента списка сделали частью обьекта, почему бы это состояние не сделать `Observable<Boolean>` и не использовать его прямо в разметке?

```
android:background="@{itemObject.isSelected ? @color/colorBlue : @color/colorGreen}"
```

При изменениях isSelected, у вас поле само будет обновляться в зависимости от состояния.
Второй же вариант по старинке, перенести установку цвета в слушатель:

```
fun bind(record : RecordItem, position: Int, listener: (RecordItem) -> Unit){
    itemView.setOnClickListener{
        if(record.isSelected){
            ////попытка менять цвет
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            itemView.tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
        listener.invoke(record)
    }
}
```

Можно вместо: `notifyItemChanged(position)` использовать: `notifyDataSetChanged()`, но тогда весь список будет перерисован что видно пользователю и выглядит так себе.

Comment: попробовал второй вариант, он не работает

Comment: а для первого как я понял, нужно использовать databinding?

Comment: Поправил, забыл про перерисовку, сам в основном пользуюсь первым методом. Да нужен databinding, я не туда глянул и подумал что вы его используете.

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: Как не работает? Вы точно используете ту вьшку что надо? Перед if добавьте: Log.e("TestingClick", "TestingClick, isSelected= $isSelected") и на пишите ответ, там может быть false или null, или слушатель вообще не работает

Comment: Valeriy false, значит handleSelected не так работает